# reversing a linkedlist using 3 pointers

Tags: python, linked-list

reversing a linkedlist using 3 pointer?
cant understand what is the problem?
pls suggest any other iterative solution too..
reversing a linkedlist using 3 pointer?
cant understand what is the problem?
pls suggest any other iterative solution too..

outcome should be 87654321(reverse of a linkedlist)
but currently the output is 1
i think there is problem in reverse function pointers

## reversing a linkedlist

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
    def push(self,data):
        new_node=Node(data)
        new_node.next=self.head
        self.head=new_node
    def printlist(self):
        temp=self.head
        print()
        while temp:
            print(temp.data,end=' ')
            temp=temp.next
    def append(self, new_data): 
        new_node = Node(new_data) 
        if self.head is None: 
            self.head = new_node 
            return
        last = self.head 
        while (last.next): 
            last = last.next
        last.next =  new_node
    def reverse(self):
        prev=None
        current=self.head
        nnext=current.next
        while nnext:
            current.next=prev
            prev = current
            current = nnext
            nnext=nnext.next
        current.next=prev
if __name__=='__main__':
    llist=LinkedList()
    llist.append(1)
    llist.append(2)
    llist.append(3)
    llist.append(4)
    llist.append(5) 
    llist.append(6)
    llist.append(7)
    llist.append(8)
    llist.printlist()
    llist.reverse()
    llist.printlist()
```

Comment: If you do not know what the problem is, no other person will know. Provide some output of your code, specify what you want to achieve and then someone can help you.

Comment: @Joanna added the expected output and expected problem in my code...

Comment: having a hard time with pointes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your code generally works fine. What you miss is assigning self.head in the end of your reverse method. Just add this line `self.head = current` to the end of reverse and it works fine.

Comment: No need for that :) Just remember to always check if the result is consistent with your class definition and update field.